# How to combine two Android source code easily?

Tags: android, android-studio

My App has two Activities, but these activities in different Android project separately.

```
Project A: com.myapp.MainActivity

Project B: com.other.MainActivity
```

Now the development is complete. I need combine them in one App

For the Java code, it is very easily, because their package are different.

But for the res, such as layout, string, values, image. Since they are in same folder, no package, no namespace, I got many conflict

Now I need spend many efforts to add prefix to each item, and then modify source cdoe to make it work.

Is there any way to combine them without any changes?

Comment: you want to make it easy via. some automated process or manually ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert both project to library project and add it to a new project or main project.

To make a project as **library** project, use

apply plugin: 'android-library' in your `build.gradle` instead 
of apply plugin: 'android'

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to combine them without any changes?

**No,** you have to make changes as mentioned by yourself in your question to resolve the conflicts (If you want to merge both into a single project).

You can refactor and rename all similarly named resources before merging, in which case it should go smooth.

Also, for scenarios like these you should plan in advance (when the end goal is known).

**EDIT:** Btw, (juse in case) if you want to use only one of the `MainActivity` for a particular installation having `productFlavors` and separate soruceSets should help.

Comment: That said, using the different modules for this would make it easier.

Comment: Actually the other project is from other company, any that is an existing project, so I can control nothing. Plan in advance is impossible. Besides, if I refactor that project, I need to do that many times when they update the code. I think library project is more reasonable solution.