# Why my Android Library got wrong resources?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-library

I asked how to combine two Android project [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058559/how-to-combine-two-android-source-code-easily)

Finally the solution is to use other project as library

So I tried following steps:

1. Create ProA, type "Project A" in TextView of  MainActivity.xml
2. Create ProB, type "Project B" in TextView of  MainActivity.xml
3. Move ProB to ProA/ProB
4. Import ProB as new Module named appB
5. Added appB to app's dependencies
6. Modify 'com.android.application' to 'com.android.library' in build.gradle of ProB
7. Delete applicationId in build.gradle of ProB
8. Remove intent-filter of MainActivity in manifests of ProB
9. startActivity to com.prob.MainActivity in com.proa.MainActivity

But com.prob.MainActivity still get the wrong layout xml file, screen will show "Project A"

What is I missing?

Comment: i got the same problem but the resources that asign incorrectly are the main color palette and the library project launcher icon(it gets replaced for an uncompiled module i got on the root project ..)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Library Project R* file for it to take from your library xml files

Suppose:
lib package: `com.library`

then do this `com.library.R.layout.main`

Comment: So do you mean I should use `setContentView(com.prob.R.layout.activity_main);` in `onCreate` of `com.prob.MainActivity`? I just tried, not work

Comment: you should package_name.R from where u want to access layout.xml file

Comment: It is really not work, I tried few ways, such as `package_name.R` , `int id = getResources().getIdentifier(“main_layout“, "layout", getPackageName()); setContentView(id);` , but no one can get correct resources file. This is the testing project: [ProA](http://sharesend.com/8q1uiw38)